# Improve my NinjectBootstrapper static class.

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, static, singleton, ninject

A NinjectBootstrapper class has been created in a Service project(responsible for getting products).
This is my code

```
public static class NinjectBootstrapper
{
   private static readonly object _thislock = new object();

   //flag to prevent bootstrap for executing multiple times
   private static bool _done;

   public static void Bootstrap()
  {
     lock(_thislock)
     {
        if(_done)
        {
           return;
        }
        _done = true;

       // services
       NinjectContainer.Kernel.Bind<IProductService>().To<ProductService>();
       // repositories
       NinjectContainer.Kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRepository>();
     }

  }

}
```

Now, while this works, I would really like to know if there are better ways to refactor my code. For instance I've read a lot of stuff about using a singleton instead of the static class. 
I'd like to really set a good base here to make it easy and flexible for future developers to extend functionality. What are some good pointers and tips I can take into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read a lot of stuff about using a singleton instead of the static class.

When applying DI we typically prefer instance classes over static classes, because we can't practice *Constructor Injection* in static classes. This doesn't mean however, that static classes are a bad practice. When classes have no dependencies and no state, `static` is fine.

This holds as well for code in the startup path, such as your `NinjectBootstrapper`. You can make it an instance class, but since this class is started directly at startup, no dependencies need to be injected (obviously, because it is the thing that wires the DI container), it would typically be useless to make this an instance class.

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation. It's true that this is indeed used at the startup. Thank you for your explanation. I'll leave my code as it is then.